# Datepicker is not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
var date_id = 1;

this.addCity = function (){

    $('#add').before('<input type="text" class="date initial hasDatepicker" id="date'+date_id+'" value="01/30/2012"></br>');
    $("#date"+date_id).live('click', function(){
        alert("#date"+date_id); //this alert works norm
        $("#date"+date_id).datepicker();
    });
}
```

The datepicker does not work, but I'm seeing no errors in the Firebug console.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In order for someone to be able to help you, you have to tell what you're trying to do and what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `.datePicker()` call to outside the click handler, i.e.

```
this.addCity = function (){

    $('#add').before('<input type="text" class="date initial hasDatepicker" id="date'+date_id+'" value="01/30/2012"></br>');
    $("#date"+date_id).datepicker();

}
```

This is because, the `.datePicker()` function is used to initialize the datePicker for a particular input element and not for rendering the datePicker immeidiately. Once initialized it will handle the click automatically.

Comment: don't help  $("#date"+date_id).datepicker();

Comment: with new created element <input type="text" ($.before()) don't work